# Borders and Inputs move when I try inserting an image

Tags: html, css, border, margin

I'm really new to programming. Whenever I try inserting an image using  it moves the border down and inputs down. I then have to move them back to match the text as shown in the picture below. I do that using "margin:" in CSS. Why do the borders and input move down when I try inserting it? Is there an easier way to position things like borders rather than using :margin:" ?

CSS(for the navbar and the input):

```
#navBar {
    border: 2px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    width: 43%;
    margin-top: -42px;
    margin-left: 405px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#searchInput {
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 1250px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 185px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    outline: none;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>Restaurant</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href= "{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
 <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&family=Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  
<img src="/static/searchImage.png" id="searchImage">
<div id="search">
  <input id="searchInput" type="text"> 
</div>

<div id="navBar">
 <a href="deals">
 <button id="dealsButton">Deals</button>
</a>

<a href="burgers">
  <button id="burgersButton">Burgers</button>
 </a>

 <a href="drinks">
  <button id="drinksButton">Drinks</button>
 </a>

 <a href="sides">
  <button id="sidesButton">Sides</button>
 </a>

 <a href="desserts">
  <button id="dessertsButton">Desserts</button>
 </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Image:

The border was perfectly aligned with the text before inserting the image and input was right next to the border. But when I insert this happens.

[image]

Comment: Can you post your html code as well? It would help to find the issue

Comment: @StelKizi Yeah, i edited it

Comment: Oh. I just realized, it's a Flask app, no? I'm not sure what the problem is because sadly I don't know this framework. But. If you use a plain link e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">` to your file, the border does not vanish

Comment: Yeah, its fine. I should've mentioned it